# Identifying date values in a text file that do not have zero padding for month and day using python strftime()

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I am reading a text file in which one of the columns (3rd) contains date values in different date formats along with other data types (string, number, etc). I am identifying each unique date format in my input file and outputting the values for each date format to a text file. One of the date formats I am looking for in my input file is - Month dd, YYYY.

For e.g. May 1, 2001.

I am using the python strftime() function to search for the above date format in my file. However, my code provided below is only outputting date values with zero-padding.

For e.g. May 01, 2001

But, I need my program to also find date values without the zero-padding that I know exist in my input file such as:

May 1, 2001

2/4/2012

I have searched the forum for the solution, and most of it involved removing/replacing the zero. However, this does not solve my problem as I am searching the file for both zero padded and non zero-padded date values.
I also tried adding the "-" sign after the "%" sign in my date format, but it did not work. I have provided my code below. Can anyone guide me in the right direction ? I am using Pycharm CE 2017.2 with the python 3.6.3 interpreter.

My Code:

```
# Identifying Month dd, yyyy date format

from datetime import datetime

import csv

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f_input, open('file2.txt', 'w') as f_output:

    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        for date_format in ['%B %d, %Y']:
            try:
                converted = datetime.strptime(row[3], date_format)
                csv_output.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], converted.strftime(date_format), row[4]])
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *very* hard to do what you want reliably using `datetime.strptime()`. I can see from your code that you are already planning to have multiple date format strings (otherwise your date format string wouldn't be in a 1-list).

Try this approach instead:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("May 1, 2001")
datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 1, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse("May 01, 2001")
datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 1, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse("2/4/2012")
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 4, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse("02/04/2012")
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 4, 0, 0)
```

So, instead of

```
for row in csv_input:
    for date_format in ['%B %d, %Y']:
        try:
            converted = datetime.strptime(row[3], date_format)
            csv_output.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], converted.strftime(date_format), row[4]])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

do

```
for row in csv_input:
    converted = parser.parse(row[3])
    csv_output.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], converted.strftime('%B %d, %Y'), row[4]])
```

This will convert *all* of your input dates to a standard format, for example "May 1, 2001". I've omitted your `try...except` because that is there to catch the cases where `strptime()` fails, and `parser.parse()` will do a competent job of whatever you pass it, as long as it isn't complete nonsense, and in that case you should not want to silently suppress the exception.

`dateutil` isn't in the standard library but it's well worth the effort of installing.

Comment: Could you also tell me where inside my for loop would I insert the parse statements that you have suggested ?

Answer (score 1):

tested in python 3.5.2 (should be same in 3.6). I see no issues

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('May 1, 2018', '%B %d, %Y')
datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('May 01, 2018', '%B %d, %Y')
datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```

You might need to paste some of the file to get a better understanding of what is going on.

**edit**

Here is a link to a [repl.it](https://repl.it). Thanks to @usr2564301 telling me about it.

https://repl.it/@ryati/GrayIllinformedFlyingsquirrel

Comment: An upvote for actually trying, although to be fair [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) *explicitly* states "`%d` Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number." ... Confirmed on https://repl.it with the language set to Python 3.6.1.

Comment: Never heard of [repl.it](https://repl.it). Great site! I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Could you tell me the purpose of the line - "datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)". When I add it to my code, I get an error on real.it saying - 
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'. 
Also, when I run - print(datetime.strptime('May 01, 2018', '%B %d, %Y')), I am getting "2018-05-01 00:00:00" as the output. Shouldn't the output be May 1, 2018 ?

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)` is output from the python console. all the lines that start with `>>>` represent my input. Basically, don't copy the output lines. They are just there to show my results.

Comment: However, I get the impression that there are more issues with your input file. Again, please provide a sample so we can properly address any other errors.